# Solving the equation $A^4=B^4+C^4$

Tags: mathematics

Let's have the following numbers:

$2\sqrt7$,  $\sqrt{\frac{7\sqrt{674}-168}{2}}$, $3\sqrt7$, $-\sqrt{\frac{7\sqrt{674}-168}{2}}$, $2\sqrt7$

Can you put these numbers into three different groups A,B,C which will solve the equation $A^4=B^4+C^4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following is probably what you are looking for

> $$(3\sqrt{7})^4 = \left( 2\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{\frac{7\sqrt{674}-168}{2}}\right)^4 + \left( 2\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{\frac{7\sqrt{674}-168}{2}}\right)^4$$ which is a result we can verify by multiplying out the quartics on the right-hand side (notice how the terms with odd powers cancel).